# Реализация списка друзей mysql

Tags: mysql, node.js

Мне нужен список друзей, я вот уже второй день ломаю себе голову как его реализовать. Знаю что можно реализовать связь один ко многим, но я подумал об одном подходе, который как мне кажется будет гораздо легче при разработке и скорости работы, но знаю что в плане организации бд этот подход кривой. Мне нужна тупая выборка принятых и не принятых друзей. Почему бы мне просто не создать в таблице пользователя 2 колонки с json строками принятых и не принятых друзей?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Нормальные формы - они не для того, чтобы программист затрахался. Они для дела. Изобретя велосипед, непременно приедешь на поле с граблями.

Answer (score 1):

Если вам нужна только "тупо" выборка с принятыми и непринятыми друзьями то вам больше подойдет NoSQL, а конкретно MongoDB.

Создаете коллекцию с документами, каждый документ это отдельный человек.
И в каждом документе можете вести два поля с принятыми и непринятыми друзьями.

В MongoDB документ представлен как обычный JSON. И также документы могут содержать разные структуры. Например если у человека нет непринятых друзей и то соответствующего поля у него тоже может не быть.